# How is infinity implemented in javascript?

Tags: javascript, infinity

In javascript division by zero will result to a value called infinity( or -infinity). Also, any arithmetic operation  on infinity with a real number will result to infinity.
I would like to know how is infinity value, and the functions that operate over it have been implemented.

Comment: [Read about IEEE 754 floating point.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point)

Comment: "any arithmetic operation on infinity with a real number will result to infinity" - false. You clearly haven't tried `Infinity * 0` ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Infinity is `1.7976931348623157E+308` in Javascript, which is a number that exceeds the **upper** limit of the floating point numbers.  There is also -Infinity, which is a number that exceeds the **lower** limirt of the floating point numbers (`-1.7976931348623157E+10308`).

Scientific notation, didn't want to *exceed* the char limit ;)